# Transcribe .docx files via python-docx to modify font and font size. Need to reconstruct paragraphs in target files

Tags: python

The intention is to transcribe .docx files to have modified font and font sizes while keeping the run attributes such as bold, underline, italic etc. I'll then add some headers and graphics to the newly created target.docx files

How to reconstruct paragraphs from runs? Each one, currently, gets it's own separate line!

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

def main(filename):
    try:
        src_doc = Document(filename)
        trg_doc = Document()

        style = trg_doc.styles['Normal']
        font = style.font
        font.name = 'Times'
        font.size = Pt(11)

        for p_cnt in range(len(src_doc.paragraphs)):
            for r_cnt in range(len(src_doc.paragraphs[p_cnt].runs)):
                curr_run = src_doc.paragraphs[p_cnt].runs[r_cnt]
                print('Run: ', curr_run.text)
                paragraph = trg_doc.add_paragraph()

                if curr_run.bold:
                    paragraph.add_run(curr_run.text).bold = True
                elif curr_run.italic:
                    paragraph.add_run(curr_run.text).italic = True
                elif curr_run.underline:
                    paragraph.add_run(curr_run.text).underline = True
                else:
                    paragraph.add_run(curr_run.text)

        trg_doc.save('../Output/the_target.docx')

    except IOError:
        print('There was an error opening the file')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main("../Input/Current_File.docx")
```

nput:

1.0 PURPOSE The purpose of this procedure is to ensure all feedback is logged, documented and any resulting complaints are received, evaluated, and reviewed in accordance with 21 CFR Part 820 and ISO 13485

Output:

PURPOSE The purpose of this procedure is to ensure

all feedback is logged,

documented and any resulting complaints are received,

evaluated, and reviewed

in accordance with 21 CFR P art 820

and ISO 13485 .

Comment: Hello, do you have a question? You want an evaluation? Please describe in words why did you post this question.

Comment: Also, could you provide the `stdout`? Where is the `'Run: ', curr_run.text ` output?

Comment: Since the `problem` was resolved on stackoverflow that means it was off-topic for this site. Could you please remove the question.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60379522/1014587)

Answer (score 0):

This modification resolves this issue.
Thanks to Scanny at Stack Overflow

```
for src_paragraph in src_doc.paragraphs:
            tgt_paragraph = tgt_doc.add_paragraph()
            for src_run in src_paragraph.runs:
                print('Run: ', src_run.text)
                tgt_run = tgt_paragraph.add_run(src_run.text)
                if src_run.bold:
                    tgt_run.bold = True
                if src_run.italic:
                    tgt_run.italic = True
                if src_run.underline:
                    tgt_run.underline = True
```